# Javassist - addMethod that returns an Object[][]

Tags: java-native-interface, javassist

My goal is to create in runtime an additional method inside a specific .class file.

A method that returns an `Object[][]`.

For that I found an amazing framework called - Javassist, a bytecode modifier framework, which helps you modify your compiled class in runtime in order to add more bytecode that represents a new method.

Managed to create a `void` method, and a method that returns a string but, for some reason, I'm unable to generate a method that returns an array or a matrix.

So far I've been struggling to find the proper way of creating such method, and got a continuous `CannotCompileException`.

Code:

```
private static CtMethod generateMethod1(CtClass declaringClass)
            throws CannotCompileException {

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append("public ").append(Object[][].class.getName()).append(" ").append("method1").append("(){")
        .append("return new").append(Object[][].class.getName()).append("{{ 1,2 }}").append("; }");
        
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        return CtMethod.make(sb.toString(), declaringClass);
    }
```

The `toString` of the generated method above is:

```
public [[Ljava.lang.Object; method1(){return [[Ljava.lang.Object;{{ 1,2 }}; }
```

Probably fails due to false jni syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Well, solved it by just replacing the `Object[][].class.getName()` with `Object[][]` literally...